# Metodo burbuja + archivo txt C#

Tags: c#

yo se como hacer el método burbuja pero tengo un problema
desconozco una forma de lograr ordenar un archivo de texto que contiene (nombre, apellido, dni)

digamos que en el archivo de texto tengo

```
Usuario 1, Cardales, 111
Usuario 2, Guztamante, 222
Usuario 3, Lopez, 105
```

como los ordeno de menor a mayor en relaciona al DNI usando el método burbuja.
Al final me tiene que mostrar de esta forma

```
Usuario 3, Lopez, 105
Usuario 1, Cardales, 111
Usuario 2, Guztamante, 222
```

Yo hasta ahora me he quedado en esta parte

```
static void ShowFile(string Files)
        {
            BinaryReader APU = null;
            try
            {
                if (File.Exists(Files))
                {
                    APU = new BinaryReader(new FileStream(Files, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
                    Empleados N = new Empleados();

                    Console.WriteLine("\n  .:|LISTA DE EMPLEADOS|:.  ");
                    Console.WriteLine("DNI \t| Nombres \t| Apellidos");
                    Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                    while (APU.BaseStream.Position != APU.BaseStream.Length)
                    {
                        N.DNI = APU.ReadInt64();
                        N.Nombres = APU.ReadString();
                        N.Apellidos = APU.ReadString();

                        Console.WriteLine("{0} \t| {1} \t| {2} ", N.DNI, N.Nombres, N.Apellidos);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Lista Inesxistente\nPorfavor cree una lista (Obcion 1)");
                }
            }
            catch (IOException a)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + a.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (APU != null)
                {
                    APU.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

Ese codigo me permite leer el archivo que tengo creado y enseñarlo, pero aun no hace el metodo burbuja la cual la tengo asi

```
static void bubbleSort(int[] array)
        {
            int aux;
            
                for (int j = 0; j < array.Length - 1; j++)
                {
                    if (array[j] > array[j + 1])
                    {
             

       aux = array[j];
                    array[j] = array[j + 1];
                    array[j + 1] = aux;
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon lo que has intentado para que se te pueda ayudar

Comment: Que código usas para guardar?

Comment: Y la pregunta cual es? porque en ninguna parte del codigo llamas a la funcion bubbleSort, y tus datos tampoco estan guardados en un array....

Comment: La verdad es que no se mucho sobre eso de listar usando el metodo de burbuja, el metodo burbuja si se, pero el problema es que estoy sacando la informacion de los empleados desde un archivo TXT

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te recomiendo lo siguiente, ya que tienes una clase Empleado, puede hacer una lista de tipo Empleado `var empleados = new List<Empleado>();`, y guardar los datos que recolectas de tu archivo de texto en esa lista, al tener estos datos puede pasarle esa lista de empleados como parámetro a tu método de ordenamiento, aquí te dejo como quedaría el método:

```
private static void BubbleSort(IList<Empleado> array)
{
            if(array == null) return;
            for (var i = 0; i < array.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                for (var j = 0; j < array.Count - 1; j++)
                {
                    if (array[j].Dni <= array[j + 1].Dni) continue;
                    var aux = array[j];
                    array[j] = array[j + 1];
                    array[j + 1] = aux;
                }
            }
}
```

De esta forma lo usarías en tu código:

```
static void ShowFile(string Files)
{
            BinaryReader APU = null;
            try
            {
                if (File.Exists(Files))
                {
                    APU = new BinaryReader(new FileStream(Files, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
                    var empleados = new List<Empleado>();

                    Console.WriteLine("\n  .:|LISTA DE EMPLEADOS|:.  ");
                    Console.WriteLine("DNI \t| Nombres \t| Apellidos");
                    Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

                    while (APU.BaseStream.Position != APU.BaseStream.Length)
                    {
                        var empleado = new Empleado
                        {
                            Dni = APU.ReadInt64(),
                            Nombre = APU.ReadString(),
                            Apellido = APU.ReadString()
                        };
                        empleados.Add(empleado);

                        
                    }

                    BubbleSort(empleados);

                    foreach (var empleado in empleados)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} \t| {1} \t| {2} ", empleado.Dni, empleado.Nombre, empleado.Apellido);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Lista Inesxistente\nPorfavor cree una lista (Obcion 1)");
                }
            }
            catch (IOException a)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + a.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (APU != null)
                {
                    APU.Close();
                }
            }
 }
```

Tomando en cuenta que yo a la clase le llame Empleado y no Empleados, para estandarizar el código.

Comment: Muchas gracias por ayudarme, pero podría colocar con mayor especificación donde va?

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya me ha funcionado el código
en verdad te lo agradezco